# mat-sort-header / mat-sort not working on a particular column

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

`mat-sort` is not working on the one column of a `mat-table` that comes from a database, the rest of the columns are working completely fine. The only difference is, I am fetching data for this one column from another service.

I tried to solve it with `ngAfterViewInit` but to no avail.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
};
```

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Resource </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.creator.name}} </td>
  <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> </td>
</ng-container>
```

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['projectName', 'date', 'hours', 'description', 'name', 'location', 'Edit'];

@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit(){
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Answer (score 33):

Not knowing your data model, something like this should solve your problem (in your `ngOnInit`):

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
  if (property === 'name') {
    return item.creator.name;
  } else {
    return item[property];
  }
};
```

The sort doesn't work on this field because Angular tries to access the column data via the string ID, which for this column is `name`, but the column data is actually located under `element.creator.name` (Angular is looking under `element.name`).

For more information check out the full documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api) (all the way at the bottom of the page) where it states:

> Data accessor function that is used for accessing data properties for
>   sorting through the default sortData function. **This default function
>   assumes that the sort header IDs (which defaults to the column name)
>   matches the data's properties** (e.g. column Xyz represents
>   data['Xyz']). May be set to a custom function for different behavior.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. It perfectly solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Needed this to sort calculated cells.

Comment: This helped resolve an issue in one column only!

Comment: I had a table with just one column and directly strings instead of objects with accessible properties. Thanks for this, helped me to get sort working that one aswell (y)

Comment: Perfect, I had a similar issue (sorting worked but not as expected) and I just renamed the column defs. and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

If one of field in your `mat-table` is not working then you need to check your `displayedColumns` with HTML code `matColumnDef`.

If that dose not match then you need to make it common as both side `ts` and `html` both.

For Ex: `displayedColumns` have NAME, TAGSCREENS at TS side and at HTML side you give some other name then sort header is not working if make it common then it will work for you.

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'tagScreens'];
dataSource= new MatTableDataSource([]);
```

You need to import these `MatSort` component

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
```

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="tagScreens">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Screens </mat-header-cell>
     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            {{ element.tagScreens.length > 0 ? (element.tagScreens | separateWithComa : seprateWithCommaPipeConst.name) : 'NA'}}
      </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>
```

For more information [Click here](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview)