# I have table that uses, angular material. I have also added matSort on the table. I could see that first column of my table is not sorting any idea?

Tags: html, node.js, angular

TS :

```
ngOnChanges() { 
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Data>(this.someData); //work order data
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

HTML :

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

<!-- column which does not sort is  : -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
                <td data-th="Customer Name" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.party.name}} </td>
            </ng-container>
```

I have tried all the way search in Google along with this site also still no answer, Have tried all the answers related to : [mat-sort-header / mat-sort not working on a particular column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004835/mat-sort-header-mat-sort-not-working-on-a-particular-column)

but no solution please help.

Comment: I have found the answer, I could see that this issue was something that I had to make some changes in : ngOnChanges
and the and is  : this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
            if (property === 'customerName') {
              return data.party.name;
            }
            else {
              return item[property];
            }
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also faced the same issue.

matColumnDef and the property name should be same.

in HTML:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="party.name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
                <td data-th="Customer Name" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.party.name}} </td>
            </ng-container>
```

in TS:

```
displayedColumns = ['party.name']; //change the column name in ts as well.
```

Also, where you are assigning the datasource:

```
      this.datasource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
              switch (property) {
                case 'party.name': return item.party.name;
case 'party.age': return item.party.age //if you have other properties as well.
                default: return item[property];
              }
            };


 this.datasource.sort = this.sort;
```

Comment: this not work because the way is defined the function `sortingDataAccessor`, see my answer

Comment: Yes, I have tried to check and could see that it was not working, But thank you so much for taking a moment to check my issue.

Comment: @Neel I've edited my answer. Please check. Actually I forgot to define the sortingDataAccessor. I hope it'll help.

Comment: Yes, this was I have also added a comment on my question and I got the answer before. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 2 issues here.

1. you are not initializing the matSort correctly.
   The code you put in the ngOnChanges should be in the ngAfterViewInit (see [official doc](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting with working code)
2. you have to help material to understand how to sort your column. Material assumes the column name is the same as your object property. So here, Material is trying to sort based on `element.Name`, which does not exists. You have to define sortingDataAccessor, telling something like "if you want to sort Name column, have a look to element.party.name instead".

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the suggestions, I have checked and also tried to modify my code which makes res now as : 
element.name but even after so it is not working buddy...

Answer (score 0):

**Update** sorry, I just check and not work, please remove upvote

<strike>use `mat-sort-header='party.name'`</strike>

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef 
                        mat-sort-header="party.name"> Name </th>
       <td data-th="Customer Name" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
           {{element.party.name}}
       </td>
</ng-container>
```

By defect short-header gets the value of the columnName but you want to sort by party.name

The best bet is add a new property "name" to the elements of your array.

**Update 2** About your comment

If you received from the API an array of object like

```
{party:{name:'',prop1:`''},prop2:''}
```

You can use pipe map in the way

```
 return httpClient.get(your url).pipe(map(res:any[])=>{
    //return your array transform
    return res.map(x=>({
         name:x.party.name,
         prop1:x.party.prop1,
         prop2:x.prop2
    })
}))
```

So your elements are in the way

```
{name:'',prop1:'',prop2:''}
```

And use a mat-table in the "normal way"

Comment: Mmmm, sorry I am lil confused as my data is being received by a service call and the structure is : data.data.name so i have been using it as : element.party.name

Comment: @Nell, about your comment, you can use pipe(map) in your service to return to your component an array with "simples properties". I update again the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can not use an object to order because how is defined the function `sortingDataAccessor` in the MatTableDataSource (see the [github](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/table/table-data-source.ts)).

But we can create a class that override this function

```
export class ObjectMatTableDataSource<T> extends MatTableDataSource<T>{
  override sortingDataAccessor= (
    data: T,
    sortHeaderId: string,
  ): string | number => {
    const part=sortHeaderId.split('.')
    let value = (data as unknown as Record<string, any>)[part[0]];
    for (let i=1;i<part.length;i++)
      value = value[part[i]];
  
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value as any)) && !isNaN(Number(value))) {
      const numberValue = Number(value);
      const MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991;
  
      return numberValue < MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ? numberValue : value;
    }
  
    return value;
  };
}
```

Now, we can use

```
dataSource = new ObjectMatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
```

And we can use mat-sort-header a name like: "party.name"

See an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkais8?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.html)